# How to export gerber with milling layer in EAGLE 9?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, gerber

I've got a pcb design with some high voltage traces that are separated with a line drawn on milling layer (46).

How to generate a valid gerber file for manufacturer (JLCPCB) with informations about this milling.

Using default 2-Layer, CAM Processor template milling isn't included into any gerber file.

Is adding milling layer into Profile file a valid way to do it?
[image]

Using: Eagle 9.3.2

Comment: https://support.jlcpcb.com/article/43-how-to-export-eagle-pcb-to-gerber-files  Do you have routing layers included?

Comment: how to export gerber files from Eagle 9.1(works with v.8+).
https://youtu.be/Jf2y1rTRHDg

Check the below video to find out how to obtain all of your CAM and Manufacturing files for your PCB designs in Autodesk EAGLE. 
https://youtu.be/Xg_uh0rsFVg

Comment: You two got a point but these tutorials do not show milling/cutouts.
I've added cam processor image. Is adding milling layer into Profile file a valid way to do inform jlcpcb about milling?

Comment: layer 46 should include outer dimension milling and interior milling . A drilled slot is a G85 code in Gerber file

Comment: Did you "Detect Board Shape" check box in "User Interface"

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the default job in EAGLE to add new Gerber files.

In the CAM processor, right-click on the `Gerber` entry in the `Output Files` section of the window. This will open a dialog that will have `New Gerber output` as an option.

[image: Illustration]

After that, you can edit that output as you would any other - Click on `Edit Layers`, add your milling layer and name it accordingly.

If your Gerbers won't make sense to the manufacturer, they will ask you to clarify (as seen on point 10 of [this article on JLCPCB website](https://support.jlcpcb.com/article/21-how-do-i-place-an-order)). At the end of the day, the only one who can say if the files are 100% valid for the manufacturing process is the manufacturer itself.